# Joining process with broadcast variable ends up endless spilling

Tags: scala, join, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am joining two RDDs from text files in standalone mode. One has 400 million (9 GB) rows, and the other has 4 million (110 KB).

```
3-grams  doc1           3-grams   doc2
ion -    100772C111      ion -    200772C222  
on  -    100772C111      gon -    200772C222  
 n  -    100772C111        n -    200772C222
... -    ....            ... -    .... 
ion -    3332145654      on  -    58898874
mju -    3332145654      mju -    58898874
... -    ....            ... -    ....
```

In each file, doc numbers (doc1 or doc2) appear one under the other. And as a result of join I would like to get a number of common 3-grams between the docs.e.g.

```
  (100772C111-200772C222,2) --> There two common 3-grams which are 'ion' and  '  n'
```

The server on which I run my code has 128 GB RAM and 24 cores. I set my IntelliJ configurations - VM options part with  -Xmx64G

Here is my code for this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("abdulhay").setMaster("local[4]").set("spark.shuffle.spill", "true")
      .set("spark.shuffle.memoryFraction", "0.6").set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "0.4")
      .set("spark.executor.memory","40g")
      .set("spark.driver.memory","40g")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val emp = sc.textFile("\\doc1.txt").map(line => (line.split("\t")(3),line.split("\t")(1))).distinct()
    val emp_new = sc.textFile("\\doc2.txt").map(line => (line.split("\t")(3),line.split("\t")(1))).distinct()

val emp_newBC = sc.broadcast(emp_new.groupByKey.collectAsMap)

val joined = emp.mapPartitions(iter => for {
      (k, v1) <- iter
      v2 <- emp_newBC.value.getOrElse(k, Iterable())
    } yield (s"$v1-$v2", 1))

val olsun = joined.reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b)

olsun.map(x => x._1 + "\t" + x._2).saveAsTextFile("...\\out.txt")
```

So as seen, during join process using broadcast variable my key values change. So it seems I need to repartition the joined values? And it is highly expensive. As a result, i ended up too much spilling issue, and it never ended. I think 128 GB memory must be sufficient. As far as I understood, when broadcast variable is used shuffling is being decreased significantly? So what is wrong with my application?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I have also tried spark's join function as below:

```
var joinRDD = emp.join(emp_new);

val kkk = joinRDD.map(line => (line._2,1)).reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
```

again ending up too much spilling.

EDIT2:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("abdulhay").setMaster("local[12]").set("spark.shuffle.spill", "true")
      .set("spark.shuffle.memoryFraction", "0.4").set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "0.6")
      .set("spark.executor.memory","50g")
      .set("spark.driver.memory","50g")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val emp = sc.textFile("S:\\Staff_files\\Mehmet\\Projects\\SPARK - scala\\wos14.txt").map{line => val s = line.split("\t"); (s(5),s(0))}//.distinct()
    val emp_new = sc.textFile("S:\\Staff_files\\Mehmet\\Projects\\SPARK - scala\\fwo_word.txt").map{line => val s = line.split("\t"); (s(3),s(1))}//.distinct()

    val cog = emp_new.cogroup(emp)

val skk =  cog.flatMap {
      case (key: String, (l1: Iterable[String], l2: Iterable[String])) =>
        (l1.toSeq ++ l2.toSeq).combinations(2).map { case Seq(x, y) => if (x < y) ((x, y),1) else ((y, x),1) }.toList
    }

    val com = skk.countByKey()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use broadcast variables. When you say:

```
val emp_newBC = sc.broadcast(emp_new.groupByKey.collectAsMap)
```

Spark is first moving the ENTIRE dataset into the master node, a huge bottleneck and prone to produce memory errors on the master node. Then this piece of memory is shuffled back to ALL nodes (lots of network overhead), bound to produce memory issues there too.

Instead, join the RDDs themselves using `join` (see description [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/api/core/spark/PairRDDFunctions.html))

Figure out also if you have too few keys. For joining Spark basically needs to load the entire key into memory, and if your keys are too few that might still be too big a partition for any given executor.

A separate note: `reduceByKey` will repartition anyway.

EDIT: ---------------------

Ok, given the clarifications, and assuming that the number of 3-grams per doc# is not too big, this is what I would do:

1. Key both files by 3-gram to get (3-gram, doc#) tuples.
2. `cogroup` both RDDs, that gets you the 3gram key and 2 lists of doc#
3. Process those in a single scala function, output a set of all unique permutations of (doc-pairs).
4. then do `coutByKey` or `countByKeyAprox` to get a count of the number of distinct 3-grams for each doc pair.

Note: you can skip the `.distinct()` calls with this one. Also, you should not split every line twice. Change `line => (line.split("\t")(3),line.split("\t")(1)))` for `line => { val s = line.split("\t"); (s(3),s(1)))`

EDIT 2:

You also seem to be tuning your memory badly. For instance, using `.set("spark.shuffle.memoryFraction", "0.4").set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "0.6")` leaves basically no memory for task execution (since they add up to 1.0). I should have seen that sooner but was focused on the problem itself.

Check the tunning guides [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/tuning.html#memory-usage-of-reduce-tasks) and [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/).

Also, if you are running it on a single machine, you might try with a single, huge executor (or even ditch Spark completely), as you don't need overhead of a distributed processing platform (and distributed hardware failure tolerance, etc).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. It was the first thing that I tried to join. I edited my question. But it failed again. Am I using join function wrongly? When joining first I use 3-grams as key and I have 40 thousand distinct 3-grams. Now I am trying countbykey definition. I am not sure if it will help:)

Comment: Mmm, let me see if I understand the question correctly. You might get away with an `aggregateByKey` which is much more efficient. What is the relationship between `100772C111` and `doc1`? Does this column have the same value on all rows? If not, then, aren't you rather aggregating by every permutation of the second column values? (i.e. `100772C111-200772C222`)?

Comment: Yeah sorry for missing info. 100772C111 is an identity number of a document. There are 17 thousand distinct doc1 in text1 and 2 million in text2. And in both texts there are no common doc number. For each doc number there are 3 grams belonging to them. Yes i try to aggregate number of common 3-grams for each different doc pair, one coming from text1 and other from text2. I edited the text samples.

Comment: And each file had the 2 columns (3gram and doc#) or 4? I don't know why do you have `split("\t")(3)`, seems too big an index. Could you actually separate the contents of File1 and File2?

Comment: There are some other irrelevant columns in the text files. For the first one the ones i want appear on the indexes 0 and 5. For the other 1 and 3. After mapping and splitting these files i get 3-gram,doc#

Comment: Hey Daniel. I have tried to follow your suggestions and edited my question again (see EDIT2). Still I end up spilling. So shuffling procedure still too expensive. Now I am experimenting by changing some feature values. I have reduced the number of cores (24 to 12) to assign them more memory. Also I am not sure how to behave for .set("park.shufsfle.memoryFraction" and "0.4").set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "0.6"). Or do you have other suggestions to apply?

Comment: Edited the answer too.